# null java.lang.AssertionError in InteliJ Ultimate plugin Android Support

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, apk

Build Succeeds but when i try to Generate Signed apk i got this error.

Exception in plugin Android Support.
with Error message null.

```
null
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.createApk(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:419)
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.createAndAlignApk(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:368)
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.access$200(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:76)
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard$1$1.run(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143716. Please use Gradle task to generate APK as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Solved After Updated SDK and Android Build tools

1. Goto Android SDK Manager

   - Check For Updates for packages
   - Android SDK tools
   - Android SDK Platform-tools
   - Please Note that **The Build-tools must be present and updated.** 
     in my case i have build-tools with rev. 23.0.3

[image: Android SDK Manager]

### Also Make Sure You Have at least one SDK Platform Installed and Updated.

- In My case :

[image: Android SDK API]